# Почему не меняются адреса dns-сервера?

Tags: сеть, ip, dns, маршрутизация, провайдер

Провайдер akado, если попытаться изменить dns-сервера в свойствах адаптера
(использовать следующие dns вместо автоматических) на dns яндекса - интернет перестает работать.

> Также интернет не будет работать, если попробовать изменить dns в
>   настройках роутера для подключения по ethernet [image: Изменение dns в настройках роутера]
>
> Но если включить яндекс dns во встроенном в роутер яндекс
>   DNS[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Интернет работает (только почему-то помимо яндекс dns, dns провайдера
>   также остаются)
>
> [image: dns серверы]

1) Почему нельзя просто сменить dns через сетевую карту либо настройки ethernet роутера (изменить-то можно, только интернет после этого не работает)?

2) И почему при включении яндекс dns в настройках роутера, dns провайдера все равно остаются? Как их убрать? И как понять к каким из dns таблицы будет подключение, к яндексу или провайдера?

3) И есть ли вообще смысл менять dns, будет ли быстрее интернет грузиться?

4) Бывают ли локальные dns, чтобы у меня на компе хранилась обновляемая база и подключение шло сразу по ip-адресу (так по идее будет быстрее грузиться)?

---

1) По первому вопросу разобрался - провайдер не дает использовать сторонние ip, если только заказывать внешний ip

Answer (score 1):

1) Почему нельзя просто сменить dns через сетевую карту либо настройки ethernet роутера (изменить-то можно, только интернет после этого не работает)?

2) И почему при включении яндекс dns в настройках роутера, dns провайдера все равно остаются? Как их убрать? И как понять к каким из dns таблицы будет подключение, к яндексу или провайдера?

Подозреваю, что прежде чем достучаться до яндекса, нужно получить адреса его днс - этим и занимаются днс провайдера. ДНС иерархическая система, вот [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS) почитайте. Не имея промежуточного ДНС нельзя достучатся выше.

3) И есть ли вообще смысл менять dns, будет ли быстрее интернет грузиться?

Подозреваю, что нет. Оптимизации есть в куда большем количестве мест. Скорость загрузки страниц упирается в ширину канала, в скорость работы браузера, скорость работы ОП и прочее.

4) Бывают ли локальные dns, чтобы у меня на компе хранилась обновляемая база и подключение шло сразу по ip-адресу (так по идее будет быстрее грузиться)?

А смысл? при любом изменении придется перекачивать всю базу. Ко многим из элементов базы Вы никогда не обратитесь, а нагрузка на канал будет большая.

Кроме того вся система ДНС построена и с учетом защиты информации от подмены.
Скачивая, Вы не можете гарантировать достоверность ответа и не можете быть уверены, что Вам не подменили при скачивании ip-адреса.

Еще советую почитать соответствующие главы из книги [Эндрю Таненбаум «Современные операционные системы»](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31649356/)

Comment: 2) Зачем получать адрес яндекс-dns у провайдера, если он указан в настройках роутера?

Comment: а если он изменится - вы же получаете от ДНС ip сервера, а не "yandex.ru"

Comment: кроме того, провайдер может поменять структуру сети

Comment: Так поэтому и указал яндекс-dns https://dns.yandex.ru/  , чтобы оттуда получать ip-адреса, а не от провайдера? И по идее этот промежуточный и есть яндекс-dns (он указан в настройках роутера)

Comment: Вам нужно получить ip dns.yandex.ru. Эту информацию Вам предоставляет следующий (за Вашим роутером) днс сервер в иерархии - это днс сервера Вашего провайдера. А зачем Вам вообще нужно менять днс сервера? откуда такая идея

Comment: ip яндексового dns  получать не нужно, потому что я его уже сам указал

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66992/discussion-between-dejsving-and--).

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Почему нельзя просто сменить dns через сетевую карту либо настройки ethernet роутера (изменить-то можно, только интернет после этого не работает)?

через сетевую карту своего компа/ноута почти всегда можно поменять. Но почему не работает интернет - это надо разбираться. Может неправильно указываете или провайдер их блокирует (а почему бы и нет). Можно просто попробовать их пропинговать.

> 2) И почему при включении яндекс dns в настройках роутера, dns провайдера все равно остаются? Как их убрать? И как понять к каким из dns таблицы будет подключение, к яндексу или провайдера?

Это специфика Вашего роутера.

> 3) И есть ли вообще смысл менять dns, будет ли быстрее интернет грузиться?

да, иногда в этом есть смысл. Но для начала я бы пропинговал днс провайдера и посмотрел  на отклик. Бывает, что у провайдера оно криво-криво настроено. И в этом случая интернет будет работать очень плохо, даже при широком канале.

Но есть dns сервера которые отдают разные ip адреса в зависимости от того, кто к ним пришел. Таким образом, к примеру, работает гугл. И если указать неверный dns, то может перебрасывать на ресурсы в США, когда есть свои местные, быстрые.

> 4) Бывают ли локальные dns, чтобы у меня на компе хранилась обновляемая база и подключение шло сразу по ip-адресу (так по идее будет быстрее грузиться)?

да. В windows мире не скажу, но в линуксе есть bind, который можно так настроить или встроенный в многие дистрибутивы dnsmask. Но только они не выкачивают всю базу - она большая и часто обновляемая. Они просто делают прозрачное кеширование. Лет пять назад это было оправдано. Сейчас же сами браузеры умеют очень эффективно кешировать dns запросы и дополнительная прослойка ни к чему.

Многие роутеры сами умеют кешировать dns запросы. Например, asus. И подключенным к нему устройствам в качестве dns отдают свой ip.

Также нужно понмнить, что многие OS не умеют корректно обрабатывать ситуацию, когда задано много dns серверов и берут первые 2.